# Check if Pandas Dataframe group has 2 specific values in a column and return those rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a groupby object. For each of these groups, I need to check, if a particular column has rows that contain value-A and value-B and return only those 2 rows within the group. If I use isin or "|" I would get cases where either one of these values are present. Right now I am doing a sloppy job of checking for first condition and then checking for second condition if first one is true and concatenating the results of both the checks.

My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from statistics import mean

dict = {'col-a': ['T1A', 'T1A', 'T1A', 'T1B', 'T1B', 'T1C', 'T1C', 'P1', 'P1'],
        'col-b': ['07:57:00', '09:00:00', '12:00:00', '08:00:00', '08:25:00', '08:15:00', '07:25:00', '10:00:00',  '07:45:00'],
        'col-c': ['11111', '22222', '99999', '33333', '22222', '22222', '99999', '22222', '99999'],
        'col-d': ['07:58:00', '09:01:00', '12:01:00', '08:01:00', '08:26:00', '08:16:00', '07:26:00', '10:01:00',  '07:46:00'],
        }

original_df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
print("original df\n", original_df)

# condition 1: must contain T1 in col-a
# condition 2: must contain 22222(variable) amongst each group of col-a
# condition 3: record containing 22222 should have col-b value between 7 and 9
# condition 4: must contain 99999(stays the same) among amongst each group of col-a where above conditions are met


no_to_check = '22222' # comes from another dataframe column

# filtering rows where col-a contains T1
filtered_df = original_df[original_df['col-a'].str.contains('T1')]

# grouping by col-a
trip_groups = filtered_df.groupby('col-a')

# checking if it contains '22222' in column c and '22222' has time between 7 and 9 in column b
trips_time_dict = {}
for group_key, group in trip_groups:
    check1 = group[(group['col-c'] == no_to_check) & (group['col-b'].between('07:00:00', '09:00:00'))]

    if len(check1) != 0:
        # checking if the group contains '99999' in column c
        check2 = group[group['col-c'] == '99999']

        if len(check2) != 0:
            all_conditions = pd.concat([check1,check2])
```

The desired output should contain one row for 22222 and one row for 99999 for each group that satisfies the criteria.

Comment: Can you include your desired output in your post as well for clarity?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can do the following with `df` as your original dataframe:

```
df[df['col-a'].str.contains('T1')].groupby('col-a').apply(lambda x: x[(x['col-c']=='22222') & (x['col-b'].between('07:00:00', '09:00:00')) & (x['col-c']=='99999').any()])
```

Yields:

```
        col-a     col-b  col-c     col-d
col-a                                   
T1A   1   T1A  09:00:00  22222  09:01:00
T1C   5   T1C  08:15:00  22222  08:16:00
```